# quotacheck: Your kernel probably supports journaled quota but you are not using it

Tags: ibm-cloud, quota, ext3

I have a Virtual Server on ibmcloud with CentOS7 and I need the quotas enabled on it. When I run command

```
quotacheck -uv /
```

it gives me following output:

```
quotacheck: Your kernel probably supports journaled quota but you are not using it. Consider switching to journaled quota to avoid running quotacheck after an unclean shutdown.
quotacheck: Quota for users is enabled on mountpoint / so quotacheck might damage the file.
Please turn quotas off or use -f to force checking.
```

I switched also to rescue mode with the purpose to switch silesystem to ext4 but the command

```
tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/xvda2
```

gives me output:

```
tune2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
Invalid filesystem option set: extents,uninit_bg,dir_index
```

Any suggestion on how to fix it?